# Context sensitive insert mode mapping or abbreviation

Tags: key-bindings, filetype-tex, abbreviations

I'm planning to implement some utility mappings for my [LaTeX plugin](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) to simplify typing of mathematics. For instance, I want to create abbreviations similar to

```
`a : \alpha
`b : \beta
-> : \to
=> : \Rightarrow
```

And similar. I want (some of) the mappings only to be available inside math environments, and not outside.

I know that I can recognize math environments through the syntax groups, i.e. `texMathZoneE` and `texMathZoneX`. However, I do not know how to use this in order to make context sensitive mappings or abbreviations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps like this:

```
let s:TeXmaps = {
    \ '`a': '\alpha',
    \ '`b': '\beta',
    \ '->': '\to',
    \ '=>': '\Rightarrow' }

function! <SID>IsTeXMath()
    return &ft ==# 'tex' && match(map( synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")' ), '\m^texMathZone[EX]$') >= 0
endfunction

for s:k in keys(s:TeXmaps)
    silent! exec 'inoremap <silent> ' . s:k . ' <C-r>=<SID>IsTeXMath()?' . string(s:TeXmaps[s:k]) . ':' . string(s:k) . '<CR>'
endfor
```

Comment: It would probably be better to use buffer-local abbreviations on just tex filetypes instead of a global abbreviation that checking `'filetype'`.

Comment: @Peter Rincker: Yes, it's just a proof of concept.  It can be optimised in many ways, f.i. by finding the numeric IDs for `texMathZoneE` and `texMathZoneX` beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

[lh-brackets](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets) provides the `Map4TheseContexts()` function that takes care of detecting the context to do different things.

```
" To be defined in a tex ftplugin -> ~/.vim/ftplugin/tex/your-shortcuts.vim
:inoremap <buffer> <silent> `a <c-r>=Map4TheseContexts('`a', 'texMathZone', '\\alpha', '`a')<cr>
" or:
:inoremap <buffer> <silent> <expr> `a Map4TheseContexts('`a', 'texMathZone', '\\alpha', '`a')
```

Note: If you have installed latex-suite, you'll have instead to use its `IMAP()` function to define your new mappings -- this is because latex-suite is quite intrusive regarding mappings.

Comment: I'm developing my own LaTeX-plugin (see link in the question). I've found latex-suite is way to complex and intrusive in general. The IMAP-functionality is not that bad, although I prefer to instead use something like UltiSnips for complex snippets.

Comment: `IMAP()` was interesting to define mappings, but mappings are harder to maintain than snippets/templates.