# How do you convert between non-literal strings and literal strings?

Tags: vimscript

I was writing a small plugin, when I decided that I should give the option of customizing which key triggers the plugin's function.  Here is an example of this:

```
let g:foo_key = "\<Tab>"
```

While this works for part of the plugin's functionality, I also need that variable as a literal string, which would be `'\<Tab>'` in this case.  Is it possible to convert from the resulting key code to a literal string?  Is there a standard way of handling this kind of option?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but you might find useful the `string()` function.  Combined with `eval()`, it makes it easy to pass things around without bending over backwards to quote values.  You can see it at work f.i. [here](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3406/1577).

Comment: I was afraid that I hadn't worded the question properly, but I don't really know how to make it clearer. Feel free to edit it.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't a snark, I'm genuinely not sure I understand what you're trying to do (so I wouldn't know how to edit your question).  Just pointing to `string()` as useful in general, not necessarily here.

Comment: If this helps at all, I am essentially wanting to convert a literal string (in single quotes) to a normal string (in double quotes) or vice versa.  The difference between literal strings and normal strings is that normal strings allow for special characters, whereas literal strings don't.

Comment: That's a level of indirection I always try to avoid.  It's usually possible, with `string()`: assignment: `let foobar="foo\tbar"`, direct use: `:echo foobar`, passing it along: `:exec 'echo ' . string(foobar)`.  Things can get hairy when writing complicated sort functions, or functions for `filter()`, `map()`, and the like.  But even then, `string()` avoids a lot of complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hex value of `g:foo_key` will be 0x09 (a tab). You can use the
[`strtrans()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#strtrans%28%29)
function to get a readable representation of this:

```
:echo strtrans("\<Tab>")
<09>
```

Note that this prints `<09>`, and not `<Tab>`. They are the same, and there is no way to know which one the user has entered. It may also show up as `^I` (depends on value of [`display`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27dy%27)).
Getting the key name is not something I can figure out how to do with a simple
function call, but in the `key_name_entry` struct in `misc2.c` you can find a
list of keynames; making a function for this is easy:

```
let g:chars = {
    \ '<09>': '<Tab>',
    \ '<1b>': '<Esc>',
\ }

fun! StringTrans(char)
    if get(g:chars, a:char, -1) != -1
        return g:chars[a:char]
    else
        return strtrans(a:char)
    endif
endfun
```

You probably want to expand `g:chars`; note that you have to type the literal
hex value with `<C-v><Tab>`, `<C-v><Esc>`, etc.

Note that this *still* won't return exactly what the user has typed, since there are multiple names for some characters (for example `<NL>`, `<LF>`, `<Newline>`, and `<Linefeed>` are all the same).

---

Doing the *reverse* with [`eval()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#eval%28%29)
is perhaps easier:

```
:let foo = '\<Tab>'
:echo foo
\<Tab>

:let foo_expanded =  eval('"' . foo . '"')
:echo strtrans(foo_expanded)
<09>
```

Comment: I figured that it would just be easier to use a literal string in the first place.  Very helpful!